# How tcl rest package uses http::config

Tags: rest, tcl

I'm using tcl rest package for executing rest API's, but i could not find any way to set the http::config options through this package. I'm using ::rest::create_interface proc for my rest call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http::config` is global to the interpreter; just call it directly. You might need to call it once to get the current configuration before the call where you need a particular setting, again to set the configuration you need, and again afterwards to reset the configuration back to what it was.

```
# I'm assuming that it's just the Accept: header that you need to control;
# it's the only config item that you need to vary a lot when doing REST.
set oldmime [http::config -accept]
http::config -accept text/frobnicated
RestCallHere...
http::config -accept $oldmime
```

I think that this is really quite annoying (but can be made easier with Tcl 8.6's `try`…`finally`…), which is why I write my REST interfaces directly on top of the http package, but that's not something that is very reusable for you. If you *do* do that, remember that the `-accept` header can be switched back immediately after the `http::geturl` call, even if you are doing an asynchronous call, since it is used immediately when constructing the actual request headers.

Comment: I understood your point, there are number of parameters covered using http::config. So I'm wandering if these parameters can be handle in rest package in ::rest::create_interface like things are being handle for headers and body.